# как сделать систему сохранений в текстовой игре на питоне?

Tags: python

собираюсь делать проект, игру на питоне, наверное это будет текстовая рпг
есть проблема, хочется сделать так, чтобы при закрытии, переменные денег, брони и оружия сохранялись.
кто знает, как такое устроить?

Comment: Вам дать ссылку на главу про чтение-запись файлов в учебнике, или в чём суть вопроса?

Comment: Ваш нужно лишь запомнить те данные, которые были записаны в памяти программы, загуглите про сериализации данных.

Comment: я просто чайник полнейший, мне надо чтобы когда игра закрывалась, данные сохранялись, можно кинуть статью, страницу)

Comment: Если чайник полнейший, то читайте любой учебник по Python

Comment: Если игра для одного пользователя, без своего сервера и надо быстро и просто, то можно воспользоваться модулем configparser и при каждом изменении данных сохранять их в файл. Для старта имхо неплохой вариант, а потом можно будет прикрутить и что-то более серьезное.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй pickle:

```
import cPickle

data = ['Test data', {'Structure':'Any'} ]
print data

# save
file = open("file.txt", 'w')
cPickle.dump(data, file)
file.close()

# load
file = open("file.txt", 'r')
data = cPickle.load(file)
file.close()
print data
```

Answer (score 1):

Импортируйте модуль

```
import configparser
```

Напишите функцию или добавьте в существующую открытие файла и запись в него результатов

```
f = open('config.ini', 'w')
f.write("score = sc" '\n')
f.write("bestscore = bestScore" '\n')
f.close()
```

Если вам нужно получить результаты при запуске то используйте

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
```